# Finding the Gaussian curvature (line of curvature)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, curvature

Problem

All the followings happen on $\mathbb{R}^3$

$r_1(t)=p(u(t),v(t))$ is a 'line of curvature' on a surface $p(u,v)$.
$q(t,s):=p(u(t),v(t))+sn(u(t),v(t)).$ ($n(u,v)$ is unit normal vector of $p(u,v)$)

Find the Gaussian curvature of $q(t,s)$.

-

My trial

Gaussian curvature = $\frac{L_1N_1-M_1^2}{E_1G_1-F_1^2}$

and the fact that $r_1$ is a line of curvature means $\frac {L_2(u'(t))^2+2M_2u'(t)v'(t)+N_2(v'(t))^2}{E_2(u'(t))^2+2F_2u'(t)v'(t)+G_2(v'(t))^2} = K_1 (K_1$ is one of two principal curvature)

After some calculating, I got $G_1=|n|^2=1, F_1=sn\cdot n'=0, E_1=...$

But I don't know how to calculate $L_1N_1-M_1^2$.
I know those definitions but it's very hard to calculate $L_1=-q_t\cdot \partial_t(\frac {q_t\times q_s}{|q_t\times q_s|}), N_1= ...$

Maybe I'm wrong anywhere above or I'm trying long way around.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q(t,s)=p(t)+s n(t)$ a surface formed by the family of stright lines normal to the surface parametrized by $p(u,v)$ along the line of curvature parametrized by $p(u(t),v(t))$. A parametrization
\begin{equation}
q(t,s)= \alpha(t)+ s w(t)
\end{equation} 
where $\alpha(t)$ and $w(t)$ are curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$, are ruled surfaces. The curve $\alpha(t)$ is called
the directrix or base curve of the ruled surface, and $w(t)$ is called the director curve. The Gaussian curvature of a ruled surface can be written as:
\begin{equation}
K=-\frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2+s^2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{w_t(t) \cdot(\beta_t(t) \times w(t))}{|w_t(t)|^2}
\end{equation}
$\beta(t)$ is a special curve, called line of stricture, which satisfies the equation
\begin{equation}
\beta(t)=\alpha(t)-\frac{\alpha_t(t) \cdot w_t(t)}{|w_t(t)|^2} w(t)
\end{equation}
As you can see the Gaussian curvature of a ruled surface is always negative or zero. More exactly $K=0$ if the mixed product $w_t(t) \cdot(\beta_t(t) \times w(t))$ is zero. In our case the curve $\alpha(t)=p(t)$, while $w(t)=n(t)$. So we have 
\begin{equation}
n_t(t) \cdot(\beta_t(t) \times n(t))=n_t(t) \cdot(\frac{d}{dt} (p(t)-\frac{p_t(t) \cdot n_t(t)}{|n_t(t)|^2} \times n(t))) = n_t(t) \cdot(p_t(t) \times  n(t))
\end{equation}

The Gaussian curvature is zero if:

- $n_t(t) = 0$, i.e. $w(t)$ is constant and the surface is a generalized cylinder
- $p_t(t) = 0$, i.e. the surface is a generalized cone
- $p_t(t) \times  n(t)=0$, i.e. the surface S is generated by lines tangent to the base curve

A smooth curve $\gamma$ on a regular surface S of class $C^2$ is called a
line of curvature if the tangent vector of $\gamma$ is a principal vector of S at all points
of $\gamma$. We can now use the Rodrigues’s theorem which says that the derivative of a normal $n(P)$
to a regular surface S of class $C^k$ with $k \geq 2$ along some direction, is parallel to it if and only if
this direction is the principal vector of the surface at $P$ and the coefficient of proportionality is equal to $−k$, where $k$ is the principal curvature of S at P corresponding to this principal vector. So we can write:
\begin{equation}
n_t(t)=-k p_t(t)
\end{equation}
In a parametric surface a curve is a line of curvature if satisfied the Rodrigues’s theorem.
Then by replacing $n_t(t)$ in the formula for the Gaussian curvature of $q(t,s)$
we have
\begin{equation}
n_t(t) \cdot(p_t(t) \times  n(t)) = -k p_t(t) \cdot(p_t(t) \times  n(t)) = 0
\end{equation}
Then K = 0$.